# How to not push certain directories/files to Github?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

Specifically for Java Eclipse projects.

Is there a reason to have anything other than src and lib directories on github??

How much value does providing /bin, /settings .classpath, .project, etc.??

I'd like to have them on my local, but not displayed on github. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

contents of my .gitignore file (which is located in my local git project directory):

```
bin/
.settings/
.classpath
.project
```

I did a git add (to add this new .gitignore file) and a git commit to my local repo.

**However**, when I push to my remote github (https://github.com/VKkaps/Breakout) now, I still see everything including the .gitignore file now? Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `.gitignore` file.
See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for more information.

Comment: Add all the files/directories which you don't want to be tracked by git to the .gitignore file. .gitignore file support patterns also. See the link provided for info. on patterns.

Comment: @ReviTezu   Where should the .gitignore file be stored?

Comment: In the same git repository, at the root of it.
For example, see: https://github.com/golang/go and open the .gitignore file.

Comment: Can you please see my edits?  Still having issues implementing

Comment: Run these command in the same order inside the repository:
1. git rm -r --cached .
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Remove ignore files"

In step-1 and step-2 - make sure to add the "." and after running the commands, you can push the commit(s) to the github and you won't see the ignored files.

Comment: Thanks!  Anywhere I can read up on what that first command is doing? I was pretty hesitant about deleting my files.

Comment: Check this: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm and you can find everything about git here: https://git-scm.com/docs/. Happy reading :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `.gitignore` file in the repo another option is Git's `exclude` file.  This file works similar to a `.gitignore` file but isn't committed to the repo.

From the [Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#explicit-repository-excludes):

> You can use this technique for locally-generated files that you don't
>   expect other users to generate, such as files created by your editor.
>
> Use your favorite text editor to open the file called
>   .git/info/exclude within the root of your Git repository. Any rule you
>   add here will not be checked in, and will only ignore files for your
>   local repository.
>
> In Terminal, navigate to the location of your Git repository Using
>   your favorite text editor, open the file .git/info/exclude Add rules
>   to the exclude file as you would the .gitignore file